# Opt-in to display post images?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images

Browsing over this thread here:

[How to lose manboobs?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/718/how-to-lose-manboobs)

Massive page-wide image of a topless fat guy. Nothing "wrong" with that, but given the fact about 10 other people can see my screen at any time, I'd rather not run into scenarios like this again.

I don't want to feel like browsing Fitness.StackExchange is something I should be embarrassed by. At the same time, making a policy to not post these images is tricky, and probably unwise.

So let's just give me an option to have to click on a thumbnail or something like that, so I don't get a screen full of moobs in the office.

Comment: Well, the title should have been fair warning. And it's not Stack Overflow, it's fitness.SE.

Comment: If you're viewing a fitness site you can expect images of people, athletic or not, partially clothed.  I strongly suggest that if you are in an environment where you cannot comfortably view such images, you avoid that site.

Comment: Don't worry so much about what your co-workers think. You don't even *want* to know what pictures *they're* looking at on the Internet.

Comment: I think something broke the funny inside of me.  Also, I think the medical term is "moobs."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are software utilities you can use, such as adblock, to block images from given services.  Some allow you to click on the image in order to view it, which appears to be your current desire.  Simply add stack.imgur.com (specifically i.stack.imgur.com) to your block list and you will be able to click to view the image.

Alternately, you can craft your own userscript that resizes all images from stack.imgur.com to thumbnail size, and onclick expand them.

I would NOT want Stack Exchange to do this for everyone by default though.